# How to minimize HDD usage in tarantool

Tags: tarantool

I have installed tarantool on a Raspberry Pi 7inch and would like to minimize its interaction with the HDD (sd card).
Are there any simple ways to do this.
What will be the real usage of hdd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a broad topic and answer would depend on tasks your application are solving. There are `memtx` and `vinyl` [engines](https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/latest/book/box/engines/) in tarantool. Each serves different goals and has own [configuration options](https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/latest/reference/reference_lua/box_cfg/). Both suitable for production use.

But I'll assume you just playing around and want to minimize disk usage as possible. For this tarantool has `temporary` spaces, which has no persistence, which means, all data are stored in memory without saving to disk.

Also, there is [`wal_mode`](https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/latest/reference/configuration/#cfg-binary-logging-snapshots-wal-mode) configuration option, which disables wal logging for an entire instance. Here is a simple example how it may be used:

```
box.cfg({ wal_mode = 'none' }) -- do not write wal logs 
box.schema.create_space('test', {temporary = true}) -- do not persist its data to disk
box.space.test:create_index('primary')
box.space.test:insert({1})
box.space.test:insert({2})
box.space.test:select()
```

There are lots of other options, you may use to tune disk usage. Check it out in [documentation](https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/latest/reference/configuration).

Comment: You should also look at `checkpoint_count` option, which reduces the number of snapshots maintained on disk, and `checkpoint_interval`, which manages how often they are written.